# Loop for counting the number of occurrences of a word in an array of words

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting, count

How would one set up a loop for counting the occurrences of a word in an array (not ArrayLists). Here is the loop I kinda set up, but printing it out just gives me an array of numbers that count from 0 to the size of the array of words. I also want to store the count values for each word into an array

```
int[] wordCountList = new int[arrayCount]; //arrayCount is just the size of the array of words
    int counter = 0;
    for(int p = 0; p < words.length; p++)
    {
        String currentItem = words[p];    //words is the array of words
        if(words[p].equals(currentItem))
        {

            wordCountList[p] = counter++;
        }
    }
```

Also, would it be better if I sorted the array in alphabetical order first and then count the occurrence of each word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is mostly fine, the only problem is, that you don't define the word you are looking for.

```
 int[] wordCountList = new int[arrayCount]; //arrayCount is     just the size of the array of words
 for(int p = 0; p < words.length; p++){
     //int counter = 0;
     for(String needle : words){
        //String currentItem = words[p];    //words is the array of words

         if(words[p].equals(needle)){
           wordCountList[p]++;
         }
     }
 }
```

For what its worth, can one count the words faster? Yes, but only by sorting(eg. bucketsort aka. hashes).

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 Stream API

```
String[] words = {"banana", "lemon", "banana", "apple"};
Map<String, Long> wordsCount = Stream.of(words).collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

`Function.identity()` has a meaning of "item itself".

Answer (score 0):

a typical approach to solving this problem is use a `HashMap` to store the occurences as key-value pairs

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(String word: words) {
  map.put(word, map.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
}
System.out.println(map)
```

now `map` is going to map each word to the number of occurrences it has, say you had the following example

```java
String[] words = {"banana", "lemon", "banana", "apple"};
```

then the map will contain

```
banana ==> 2
lemon => 1
apple => 1
```